# How to fix the IE Security warning due to certificate errors using vbs?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, internet-explorer-8, certificate

I have an issue with the the url which I uses for testing,where it loads in IE with the following error,

***"To help protect your security,Internet Explorer has blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors.Click here for options..."***

This causes the page to not load properly with it content and my script fails here and the clicking on the any of the links or image or button wont work.

I'm using html dom using the vbs for running my automation script and is looking for a solution either regedit or updating the IE options using the vbscript.

Below is the screenprint of the error which I get in IE
![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Use a valid certificate.

Comment: please attach the screenpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider adding the following block to your VBScript. Please note that this works for IE11:

```
Set ElementCol = IEObj.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")                
'Get all links on web page                                            
'Grap/click the link we are looking for...                            
For Each Link In ElementCol                                           
If Link.innerHTML = "Continue to this website (not recommended)." Then
Link.Click                                                            
Exit For                                                              
End If                                                                
Next
```